# htaccess rewriterule adds unwanted get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

What I have in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# --- Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)/?$ /uk/city/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What I like it to do is redirect `example.com/city/london` to `example.com/uk/city/london`

The weird thing is that it now redirects to `example.com/uk/city/london?city/london` so it seems it adds the part it needs to redirect as a get parameter to the new URL.

Also tried `Redirect 301 /city/london http://www.example.com/uk/city/london` but this gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep `R=301` (redirect) rule before internal routing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^city/([^/]+)/?$ /uk/city/$1 [R=301,L]

# --- Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also clear your browser cache to test this to avoid hitting old 301 cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if the Redirect 301 did not work:

```
RewriteRule /city/london uk/city/london [L]
```

Here's an example with your other defined .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule /city/london uk/city/london [L]

# --- Remove index.php from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```